# Clojure eval with Math functions

Tags: clojure, eval, leiningen, clojure-repl

I'm having problems eval-ing a LazySeq returned by Deriva:

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix)
(use 'com.lambder.deriva.core)

(def f1 '(cos (* x y)))
(def f2 '(sin (* x y)))
(def f [f1 f2])
(def u ['x 'y])
(def x 4)
(def y 3)
(defn jacobian [f u]
    (map #(partial-derivative f %) u)
)
```

Returns a LazySeq

```
((vector (* (* -1 (sin (* x y))) y) (* (cos (* x y)) y)) (vector (* (* -1 (sin (* x y))) x) (* (cos (* x y)) x)))
```

Which can be successfully eval-ed using the REPL:

```
(eval (into [] (jacobian f u)))
```

Results in the correct matrix

```
[[1.609718754001305 2.5315618761974763] [2.1462916720017398 3.3754158349299686]]
```

If I put the eval inside the clj file and `lein run`

```
(defn -main
  []
  (eval (into [] (jacobian f u)))
)
```

I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: sin in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init2786363415298022761.clj:1:113)` since `eval` works in a different namespace.

Is there any way to include the clojure.math functions in the temporary namespace generated by eval? Or is there a better way to evaluate the expression?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use java.lang.Math/sin function of java.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using syntax-quote (`) instead quote (') to obtain fully qualified symbols that you can later eval:

```
's
=> s
`s
=> user/s
```

See more about quoting here:
https://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html